# cadvisor : Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/kdump.service"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cadvisor

When staring the cAdvisor, I am getting `Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/kdump.service"`. I am trying to understand what these are for, and ... How can resolve?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

## My `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.7"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    privileged: true
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/cgroup:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct:/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct,cpu:rw
    command: ["-logtostderr", "-docker_only", "-v=4"]
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - internal
    labels:
      - "org.label-schema.group='monitoring'"
```

## My `cAdvisor` logs

```
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216181       1 factory.go:218] Factory "systemd" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/auditd.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216195       1 factory.go:211] Factory "raw" can handle container "/system.slice/auditd.service", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216209       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/auditd.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216216       1 factory.go:218] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-containers-338c650e497d25342cd554c2dcddda597a8ae1f6f1af9d38ddffa4768d51c512-shm.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216232       1 factory.go:211] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-containers-338c650e497d25342cd554c2dcddda597a8ae1f6f1af9d38ddffa4768d51c512-shm.mount", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216246       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-containers-338c650e497d25342cd554c2dcddda597a8ae1f6f1af9d38ddffa4768d51c512-shm.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216255       1 factory.go:218] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/kdump.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216264       1 factory.go:218] Factory "systemd" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/kdump.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216285       1 factory.go:211] Factory "raw" can handle container "/system.slice/kdump.service", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216306       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/kdump.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216329       1 factory.go:218] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay2-7aee40d9806631c761a0d7a9bb1bfde1a70260590437020231fc16fa6cf8cc9b-merged.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216353       1 factory.go:211] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay2-7aee40d9806631c761a0d7a9bb1bfde1a70260590437020231fc16fa6cf8cc9b-merged.mount", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216384       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay2-7aee40d9806631c761a0d7a9bb1bfde1a70260590437020231fc16fa6cf8cc9b-merged.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216397       1 factory.go:218] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/kmod-static-nodes.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216406       1 factory.go:218] Factory "systemd" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/kmod-static-nodes.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216419       1 factory.go:211] Factory "raw" can handle container "/system.slice/kmod-static-nodes.service", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216432       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/kmod-static-nodes.service"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216446       1 factory.go:218] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/dev-hugepages.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216455       1 factory.go:211] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/dev-hugepages.mount", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216468       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/dev-hugepages.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216475       1 factory.go:218] Factory "docker" was unable to handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay2-70cd980dc4c48095d4c7060b7626642d71513451d4dd63e896d789ea7b04e394-merged.mount"
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216489       1 factory.go:211] Factory "systemd" can handle container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay2-70cd980dc4c48095d4c7060b7626642d71513451d4dd63e896d789ea7b04e394-merged.mount", but ignoring.
today at 22:27  I0114 21:27:59.216502       1 manager.go:917] ignoring container "/system.slice/var-lib-docker-overlay2-70cd980dc4c48095d4c7060b7626642d71513451d4dd63e896d789ea7b04e394-merged.mount"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kdump.service` is a system service, not a Docker container. You can read more on it [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-kdump). What you see in logs is debug information, telling you that cAdvisor has no handler for kernel dump service. This is not an error and it is only visible because you've increased verbosity (`"-v=4"` in your `command:`). You can either decrease verbosity or simply ignore these messages.